# What is using my Azure Cores?

Tags: azure

I went into the Azure portal  (portal.azure.com), and it showed that I had 3 virtual machines running in US East 2, with a total of two Standard A1 VMs (1 VCPU and 1.75 GB of RAM), and a DS2v2  VM (2 VCPUs and 7 GB RAM).

But went I went into the side of the Azure portal (Cost Managament + Billing -> Usage & Quotas), it said that I was using 10 DS2v2 cores and 6 Standard A0-A7 cores in US East 2.

Is there a way that I can figure out what is using the other cores?

Comment: This question, unfortunately, is off-topic for StackOverflow.  But... just look at the 'All resources' blade in the portal to see everything you've created. If it doesn't align with your billing, then open a billing ticket.

Comment: If you use `get-azurermvm` and `get-azurevm`, could you get all VM in your subscription?